# How fast was Soren's probe traveling to have reached its destination in approximately 10 seconds?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-generations

In *Star Trek: Generations*, Dr. Tolian Soran shoots a [solar probe](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Solar_probe) into the nearest star in order to

> shift the Nexus.

So, if the star is approximately the same distance away from Earth, how fast would the probe actually have to be travelling to reach the star in the allotted time and is there any indication what allowed this speed to be reached?

Comment: What’s your question? The headline and the body are asking two completely different questions (and one of them is a basic astronomy question with no science fictional input needed).

Comment: “if the star is approximately the same distance away from Earth” — have we got any reason to think that it is?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite What reason do we have to think that it might be, for instance, as close as the Moon is to Earth?  Ten seconds is pretty short travel time...

Comment: I think we can chalk the event, and its aftermath, up to "bad movie physics".

Comment: I think that the question has a definite in-Universe answer. See both mine and Zeiss' answers.

Comment: Zeiss, it's a star! If they were as close as the moon is to the earth, they would indeed be dead.

Comment: Do they really say it's "conventionally propelled" (by which I presume you mean sub-warp)? I don't remember that...

Comment: @TáibhséGaeilge I added some clarifications in your question: it was a probe not just a rocket and I added the "bad guy's" name, which is Dr. Tolian Soran.

Comment: @TáibhséGaeilge: but it could like like a really *mild* star.

Comment: One fan theory is that everything from when Picard first arrives on the planet is his heatstroke-induced delusion and none of it ever happened ;)

Comment: I've added a rider asking for details of the probe itself.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It's G-type like the Sun. Please see my answers for details :)

Comment: @Loki: I already did! Excellent work.

Comment: "have we got any reason to think that it is?"

Yes, it's got life.

Why do you people make asking a simple question next to impossible. 

He's basically asking how fast from Earth to the Sun in ten seconds. What else could he possibly be asking!

Comment: Judging from the question I'd assume you're talking about the second probe launched from Viridian 3 as opposed to the first launched from the Armagosa observatory early on but it would help to clarify in the question.

Comment: Of course, the real physics pedants were scoffing at the missile being able to stop stellar fusion, or that stoppage having an effect that could be seen within several thousand years, or this having any effect on the star's gravitational pull.

Answer (score 49):

The relevant scene described by the OP takes place at the Veridian system. According to the [Star Trek: Star Charts](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Veridian) (p. 65):

> Veridian was classified as a G-class star.

All [G-type stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-type_main-sequence_star) have a mass of 0.84 to 1.15 solar masses and surface temperature of between 5,300 and 6,000 K, so we can safely assume that Veridian is roughly similar in mass and temperature to our Sun. Therefore, any habitable planets will be at a distance of roughly one astronomical unit (AU) or so, which corresponds to the "Goldilocks zone".

Then, assuming the distance from the planet to its star to be around 1AU, the probe should be travelling at warp ~3 in order to hit the star in around 10 secs.

The reason for this is that 1AU is ~8 light minutes or ~480 light seconds, so for the probe to cover the distance in say 10 secs it has to be travelling at a speed of 48c (c=speed of light). According to the [wiki](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Warp_factor#Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation) and the warp diagram from the [TNG Technical Manual](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual) seen below, 48c is about warp 3.

[image]

Since Starfleet's [Class 8](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Class_8_probe) probes can reach warp 9 and are no bigger than a photon torpedo, it is certainly plausible for a small probe like the one used by Soren to reach warp 3 given the available tech at the time.

Comment: Warp speeds seem to have no consistency in the ST universe, but a fair answer nonetheless.

Comment: Most of the stuff about warp factors in the wiki, such as the famous warp diagram, comes from quotes from various episodes and the TNG Technical Manual. The latter was created by Sternbach  and Okuda to be a reference guide for the series and is not 100% canon, but it's as close we can get.

Comment: Don't forget that the Veridian system had two habitable planets (the second one had a primitive species on it). So the Goldilocks zone may have been larger than normal for...reasons.

Comment: Also, would it be feasible for the probe to go to warp essentially as soon as it was launched with no effects to the planet, or the platform that Soran and Picard were on?

Comment: It would have to clear the atmosphere first  (first 100km or so) I guess and then go to warp.

Comment: This planet seems to be more arid (desert-like), so probably is closer to the star.

Comment: @Loki Just curious, but what is the evidence that a warp drive could be so small that it could fit in that rocket when even escape pods had 2 big nacelles?

Comment: @By137 Remeber that Soren was the same species as Guinan, and her species is described as being incredibly long lived and incredibly technologically advanced.  So, with a plentiful supply of handwavium, he built a Tech 37 warp drive that can fit in a missile, unlike the Enterpris's Tech 20 nacelles (numbers totally made up.)

Comment: @By137 Starfleet's Class 8 probes can reach warp 9 and are no bigger than a photon torpedo, so Soren's probe reaching warp 3 is plausible. I've added this in the answer along with sources.

Comment: @Loki Heck, photon torpedoes hit warp all the time

Comment: @AzorAhai According to the TNG Manual, photon torpedoes can travel at warp if they are launched while at warp, otherwise when launched at sublight they move at high impulse. In other words they do not cross the warp barrier. Hence, I think the probe is a better example ;-)

Comment: But even if it reached the star in 10 seconds, Soren, Picard and we as the viewers still shouldn't have been able to see the star go dark as quickly as it did from the surface of Veridian III --> the device impacted the star minutes before it was launched --> it had to travel through time (maybe due to some temporal phasing effects due to the nearby and closing Nexus)...

Comment: @BMWurm Out of universe: While technically correct, that would be very anticlimactic... In universe: trilithium causes a quantum implosion which presumably affects subspace, so what we see is probably related to that.

Comment: @Loki But if the effects propagate faster than light why did the Enterprise jump only to Warp 1 when escaping Amargosa? ... Although it would be entirely possible that only the visual is affected ;)

Comment: @BMWurm Ok I don't know, I give up ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 12):

Assuming a similar distance from planet to star as that of Earth, eight light minutes, then the missile had to travel at approximately 50 times light-speed to arrive at the star in ten seconds.  That is very much within the realms of Star Trek technology.

More importantly, though, the missile traveled at the speed of plot. Had this been a more suspense-driven plot element, or one the Enterprise crew were intended to have a reasonable opportunity to stop, the same missile fired from the same planet might have take half an hour or more to make the same trip.

Answer (score 2):

It has to be traveling backwards in time.

It's a life sustaining planet in orbit around a star that's between white and yellow in color. This puts light-delay from the star surface to the planet somewhere around 6-9 minutes. We see the effect of the probe on the star from the planet's surface in ten seconds.

It took effect ten seconds after launch. Dude, Warp 10's not enough! It's gotta get there at least 6 minutes before it was launched. Ordinary speed definitions don't really apply anymore. And due to the limitations for how time travel works in Star Trek you've got a serious problem.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up this bold statement?

Comment: @Valorum: I fail to understand why high school physics doesn't suffice. Sun-like star -> life zone 6-9 light minutes away from star -> 6-9 minutes to notice the star isn't giving off daylight anymore. But the planet darkens in 10 seconds on screen.

Comment: Actually we know from the new Star Trek films that the shockwave from an exploding star can travel at warp speeds

Comment: @Valorum: In which case an observer on the surface would see the shockwave only after it passed while seeing the star on the surface for the next 8 or so minutes.